# Add event to submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have just started studying js with this js code

```
<div class="container">    
    <form name="myForm" action="#"  method="post">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="smit">
    </form> 

  <script>
var smit=document.getElementById("smit");
smit.addEventListener("click",formvalidate(),false); 

function formvalidate(){

    console.log(" vua moi click submit");

    if(t==null){
        var t= document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if(t==null || t==""){
             alert("xin dien vao email");

        }
    }

}
</script>
```

When previewing in browser, a alert popup auto appear despite i not click on submit button.
Can anyone please explain me what happening? 
Thanks.

Comment: which browser you are testing on?

Answer (score 6):

The parentheses after your function name causes the function to be *called* right away. Since you're just assigning it as the event listener, you want to *pass* it.

Remove the parentheses and it'll wait for the click before executing:

```
smit.addEventListener("click", formvalidate, false);
//                                        ^^ No parentheses
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made some little changes so it'll work in IE as well:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="#"  method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="smit">
</form>

<script >
function formvalidate(event){
//removed console log because that only works in ie
// when debugging
    var t= document.getElementById("fname").value;
    if(t==""){
       alert("xin dien vao email");
       if(event.preventDefault){ event.preventDefault()}; 
       if(window.event){window.event.returnValue = false;}
    }
}
var smit=document.getElementById("myForm");
if(smit.addEventListener){
    smit.addEventListener("submit",formvalidate,false);
}else{
    //ie doesn't have addEventListner
    smit.attachEvent('onsubmit', formvalidate);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove parenthesis from formvalidate, like:

```
smit.addEventListener("click",formvalidate(),false);
```

to

```
smit.addEventListener("click",formvalidate,false);
```

See: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Event listener does not contains parenthesis, removes it .if you add parenthesis to it , it looks like function but here you have to assign your eventlistener.

```
smit.addEventListener("click",formvalidate,false);
```